# Can I use subquery in a user-defined function

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, user-defined-functions

I try to use subquery in mysql custom user-defined function I get an error so could u help me with one example.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `findsubName`(counts INT) 
RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
DECLARE result VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE v_name VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE finished INT(1) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT id, (SELECT t_name FROM ajctb_titles b WHERE a.jt_id=b.t_id)
   as tableName FROM ajctb_vacancies a limit counts;

   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
   FOR NOT FOUND 
   SET finished = 1;

   OPEN my_cursor;
   calc_change: LOOP
   FETCH my_cursor INTO v_name;

   IF finished THEN
     LEAVE calc_change;
   END IF;
   IF result<>'' THEN 
     SET result = CONCAT_WS(',',result,v_name);
   ELSE
     SET result = v_name;
   END IF;
   END LOOP calc_change;
   CLOSE my_cursor;
  RETURN result;
END
```

Error message:
Error Code: 1328. Incorrect number of FETCH variables

Answer (score 0):

*Error message: Error Code: 1328. Incorrect number of FETCH variables*

Error messages attempt to tell you what the problem is. It is in the FETCH. Looking at the documentation:

> **13.6.6.3 Cursor FETCH Syntax**
>
> FETCH [[NEXT] FROM] cursor_name INTO var_name [, var_name] ...
>
> This statement fetches the next row for the
>   SELECT statement associated with the specified cursor (which must be
>   open), and advances the cursor pointer. If a row exists, the fetched
>   columns are stored in the named variables. **The number of columns**
>   **retrieved by the SELECT statement must match the number of output**
>   **variables specified in the FETCH statement**.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fetch.html

2 columns in your query:

```
SELECT
    id
  , (
        SELECT
            t_name
        FROM ajctb_titles b
        WHERE a.jt_id = b.t_id
    )
    AS tableName
```

means **2 variables are needed the FETCH**

It hasn't even attempted the subquery yet.

Regarding that **correlated subquery** it could be a problem. When you use a subquery in the select clause like this it **MUST** return no more then one value. So you should use `limit 1` if you continue with that subquery.

That subquery can be replaced with a join. e.g.

```
SELECT
    id
  , b.t_name AS tableName
FROM ajctb_vacancies a
LEFT JOIN ajctb_titles b ON a.jt_id = b.t_id
```

You may want to use an `INNER JOIN` if you must always have a non-null tablename returned.